# Как подключить bean в component?

Tags: java, xml, spring, config

Имеется бин:

```
    <spring:bean id="client" class="com.example.Client">
        <spring:property name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <spring:property name="port" value="27017"/>
        <spring:property name="dbName" value="test"/>
    </spring:bean>
```

Есть класс, в который его нужно подключить:

```
public class Document {
    private Client client;
}
```

В файле, где все флоу настраиваются

```
        <service name="SaveDocumentService">
            <inbound>
                <vm:inbound-endpoint path="save-document-service" />
            </inbound>
            <component class="com.example.Document" />
        </service>
```

Как я могу в этот компонент подключить bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, это уникальный синтаксис для sping 2 или нет, но вот, что сработоло:

```
<component>
    <spring-object bean="document"/>
</component>

<spring:bean id="document" class="com.example.Document"  >
    <spring:property name="client" ref="Client"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если отбросить в сторону, что настройка бинов в Spring через XML это уже моветон, то нужно сделать так:

```
<bean class="com.example.Document" id="document>
    <property name="client" refid="client"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Возможно сработало, однако после сборки war и перебрасывании файлов  на удалённый сервер и запуск дебага выдает source code does not match the bytecode. При этом breakpont определяются. У вас есть ещё идеи?